# OpenAI API error: "The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY env variable"

Tags: python, environment-variables, openai-api, api-key, gpt-3

I'm a little confused about using OpenAI in Python and need a little help to make this code work. I tried several solutions found on StackOverflow, none of them are working.

My goal is to make a Python code that asks two questions to the user, and then the `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` model finds the answer and exports a `questions_reponses.csv` with it. I will then convert this to XML to import it into a moodle environment.

**Error message**: `OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable`

**Environnement**: MacOS/Thonny

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd

# Configure OpenAI API key

from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
openai.api_key = 'my secret key openai'


# Prompt user for 2 questions
questions = []
for i in range(2):
    question = input("Posez une question: ")
    questions.append(question)

# Use OpenAI to answer questions
answers = []
for question in questions:
    response = client.Completions.create(
        engine="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
        prompt=f"Question: {question}\nRéponse:",
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.7,
    )
    answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    answers.append(answer)

# Create a pandas dataframe with questions and answers
df = pd.DataFrame({"Question": questions, "Réponse": answers})

# Export dataframe to CSV file
df.to_csv("questions_reponses.csv", index=False)

print("Le fichier CSV a été créé avec succès.")`
```

I've tried to set the environment variable `OPENAI_API_KEY` in my os, but it didn't work (I always get the same error message). So I keep trying to set the key inside the code below. I don't know if my syntax is okay.

##### Remark on the answer

I am reaching out to the answerer here. As to the rules of Stack Exchange, I must do this in the question.

I've just tried option 1, same error message:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Configure OpenAI API key

    import os
    from openai import OpenAI
    client = OpenAI()
    OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

    # Prompt user for 5 questions
    questions = []
    for i in range(1):
        question = input("Posez une question: ")
        questions.append(question)

    # Use OpenAI to answer questions
    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        response = client.Completions.create(
            engine="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
            prompt=f"Question: {question}\nRéponse:",
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.7,
        )
        answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        answers.append(answer)

    # Create a pandas dataframe with questions and answers
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Question": questions, "Réponse": answers})

    # Export dataframe to CSV file
    df.to_csv("questions_reponses.csv", index=False)

    print("Le fichier CSV a été créé avec succès.")
```

I've just tried option 2, same error message:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Configure OpenAI API key

    from openai import OpenAI
    client = OpenAI()
    OpenAI.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"




    # Prompt user for 5 questions
    questions = []
    for i in range(1):
        question = input("Posez une question: ")
        questions.append(question)

    # Use OpenAI to answer questions
    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        response = client.Completions.create(
            engine="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
            prompt=f"Question: {question}\nRéponse:",
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            stop=None,
            temperature=0.7,
        )
        answer = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        answers.append(answer)

    # Create a pandas dataframe with questions and answers
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Question": questions, "Réponse": answers})

    # Export dataframe to CSV file
    df.to_csv("questions_reponses.csv", index=False)

    print("Le fichier CSV a été créé avec succès.")
```

I don't understand what is going on.

##### MIND: the answer works, it was just not checked in full

*This is a remark from an outsider.* As to the check of the heading above: the questioner has only tried the approach 1. With approach 2, it would work, that is why the questioner could already accept the answer.

Comment: The syntax might have changed. Try   

```
client = OpenAI(
   api_key='my secret key openai',
 )
```

Comment: that's ok with this syntax ! thank U very much !

Comment: openai makes terrible job  with those changes

Answer (score 3):

You have two options how to set the OpenAI API key.

**OPTION 1 (recommended): Set the OpenAI API key as an environment variable**

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
```

*Note: After you set an environment variable, you need to restart the computer! Only after restarting the computer will the environment variable start working.*

**OPTION 2**

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

However, there's a slightly different approach displayed in the official [GitHub repository for the OpenAI Python SDK](https://github.com/openai/openai-python?tab=readme-ov-file#usage):

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)
```

So, now we have two approaches to setting the OpenAI API key as an environment variable:

**OPTION 1 - APPROACH 1**

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
```

**OPTION 1 - APPROACH 2**

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
)
```

The difference is that the first approach sets the API key **after** creating the OpenAI class instance, while the second approach allows you to set the API key **during** instantiation by passing it as a parameter.

I tested the first approach with the newest OpenAI Python SDK version, and it still works.

Comment: You forgot to show option 2 - approach 2: `client = OpenAI(api_key = "sk-...")` without an environment variable. For me, both approach 2 work, the two approach 1 do not work for me, throwing the error in question. I am on `openai 1.10.0`.

Comment: @questionto42 Of course, this is another option, but I intentionally didn't add it because I wanted to push people to use environment variables. If you give people multiple options, which one will they pick? The easiest/quickest one. I cannot say how many times I've seen leaked OpenAI API keys on StackOverflow over the past year. Thanks for the feedback. Hm, I will do some additional tests and edit my answer if necessary.

Comment: If you work on a Jupyter Notebook server, you can only write the API key inside the cells, not outside in your own command prompt. You can `%set_env ...` an environment variable at first or run `!export ...` to avoid typing that API key again and again if you code more than one test. You are right.

Comment: You can find this answer also in the guide of pypi [OpenAI](https://pypi.org/project/openai/).

Comment: If you set it it in an environment variable, it tries to fetch it from there by default. For example, if I loaded some new code and overwrote the client by chance, it threw: `OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable`. I guess you are right in pushing this as best practice. But it also works if you have once set the key with option 2 approach 2 and then check it with client.api_key (client as the openai object). If it has it, you do not need to load it again.

Comment: Option 1 approach 2 worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

First `pip install python-dotenv`

Then set your .env file

```
OPENAI_API_KEY="*****"
```

NOW

```
    import os
    from openai import OpenAI
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
    load_dotenv()
    
    client = OpenAI(
        api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    )

    //CODE HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the openai version first, above answers might work for older versions

`pip show openai`

```
Version: 1.13.3
Summary: The official Python library for the openai API
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: OpenAI <support@openai.com>
License:
```

following is the another approach to set OPENAI_API_KEY for openai version 1.x.x,

```
import os
import openai

key = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 

OR

key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']

client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=key)
```